# tortoise-tts mac m1 silicone

Tags: python, text-to-speech, huggingface

I've been trying to set up tortoise on a virtualenv.
I am able to run do_tts.py and the code provided in `tortoise_tts.ipynb`.
However, I would like to run it with longer texts, thus trying `read.py` and `read_fast.py`

In doing so, I get an error stating I don't have a GPU, so good so true, but I am not sure where to change the settings as stated

```
raise RuntimeError('Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA '
RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu') to map your storages to the CPU.
```

In which file in which line am I supposed to change that?
I checked if the files `read.py` and `read_fast.py` contain torch.load, but they don't, so I am wondering where can I make the necessary changes? (I have not made changes to the above mentioned py files, so if you could help me in clarifying where to make the change in the original code, that would be much appreciated.)

Best